# How to the change BackgroundColor of a Button at runtime in Android?

Tags: java, android, button, colors

The code below changes the background color to black, no matter what color I pass as an 
argument.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    b.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
getResources().getColor()
```

like the following:

```
b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is a really late answer, but I just came across with your question

you can use

```
b.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white)
```

or

```
b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```